# Invalid Bind expression type of <sobject> for id field SObject Account

Tags: apex, soql, list

I'm getting this error "Invalid Bind expression type of Class_Detail__c for id field SObject Account"

Class_Detail__c.Student__c is a Master-Detail relationship field to Account. 
Basically I want to select a list of students from Account object using the ids (Student__c) from the Class_Detail__c custom object. What am I doing wrong?

```
id classid = lstOfPI[0].iClassID;
id teacherid =  lstOfPI[0].iTeacherid;


List<Class_Detail__c>  lstClass= [Select student__c from Class_Detail__c WHERE ClassID__c = :classid];

List<Account> lstStudentProfilesToUpdate = [SELECT Id,Teacher__c FROM Account WHERE id in :lstClass];
```

Comment: Can you sketch the data model and explain what you want in a more precise maner.The explanation you have is not clear and this post might get down votes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that you're providing in your Apex bind expression is of the wrong type.

```
List<Account> lstStudentProfilesToUpdate = [
    SELECT Id, Teacher__c 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE id in :lstClass
];
```

Here, `lstClass` is a `List<Class_Detail__c>`. Your bind variable for the `Id` column on `Account` must be a collection of `Id` values.

You need to iterate over your collection of `Class_Detail__c` records to accumulate their associated `Student__c` field values, which if I understand you correctly is the lookup field pointing to Account.

```
List<Class_Detail__c>  lstClass= [Select Student__c from Class_Detail__c WHERE ClassID__c = :classid];

Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Class_Detail__c s : lstClass) {
    accountIds.add(s.Student__c);
}
```

Then bind to `accountIds`.

Alternately, if you don't need `lstClass` for some other purpose, you can simply use an `IN` subquery here, because you're matching columns of type `Id` that refer to the same object:

```
List<Account> lstStudentProfilesToUpdate = [
    SELECT Id, Teacher__c 
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Id in (
        SELECT Student__c 
        FROM Class_Detail__c 
        WHERE ClassID__c = :classid
    )
];
```

Comment: As a side note, if your `WHERE` clause were to filter on the Id value of the same object you were querying, binding the `List<Class_Detail__c>` would have worked. I'm not 100% sure if you would be able to use a `List<Account>` to bind to `ClassId__c` or not, but the big point here is that if you're binding a `List<SObject>`, the subtype of `SObject` needs to match the `SObject` that your relationship value points to.